# DataGrid set single cells readonly

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, wpfdatagrid

I am looking for a way to disable some of my cells in a WPF DataGrid. Since [isReadOnly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.isreadonly%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is not a [DependencyProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.aspx), I can not use it.

Is there any other way to do this?

I would like to write something like this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="{Binding Path=Value,Converter={StaticResource ValueToBooleanConverter}}" />
```

but any way how to do this would be nice, since I don't see a way, but Splitting the data in different `DataGrid's`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can`t make a column read-only, you can go to a cell level. For example by making `Style` and adding it to required columns:

```
 <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding TextProperty}">
      <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
           <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
               <Setter Property="IsEnabled" 
                       Value="{Binding Path=Value,Converter={StaticResource ValueToBooleanConverter}}" />
           </Style>
       </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
 </DataGridTextColumn>
```

I made the `Style` inside column here but of cource it can be moved to resources and referenced in any required columns by key (but you gotta be shure converter is accessible for that style). Cell`s `IsReadOnly` doesn`t seem to have a setter so I`m using `IsEnabled` here which is doing the job quite nicely.

Comment: When the cell is disabled, it can not be selected anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DataGrid.OnBeginningEdit` event:

```
void DataGrid_OnBeginningEdit(object sender, DataGridBeginningEditEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridRow row = e.Row;
    var viewModel = (YourViewModel) row.Item;
    if (<Test to check if it is the expected column> 
      && viewModel.Value == <?>) e.Cancel = true;
}
```

This does not break MVVM. The behavior is driven by a property of your view model (something you can test) and there is only basic code to bind the property to the view.